# How to clone TYPO3 extension?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I would like to make a copy of an extension as a base for my own extension.  How can I clone a TYPO3 extension to start my own with the same behaviour.
What are the files and parameters I have to change?

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look into this script on github:
https://github.com/colorcube/typo3_clone_extension

Basically you have to replace all instances of the Extension key e.g. "my_ext", as well as filenames containing the key.

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* clone an existing extension and change extension key, plugin names, namespaces, database tables etc. (a simple search / replace might work in most cases, make sure to do it case-sensitive though!) ...

But, have you considered using the [extension_builder](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/extension_builder/) as an alternative to kick-start your new extension? For version 8.7 use the [extension_builder from github](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/extension_builder/tree/8.7).

Answer (score 0):

If you want manually change the EXT-Key & -Vendor, you have to do the whole way, I did some weeks before ;).

#### Copy your Extension

With Shell:

```
cp -r source_ext target_ext
```

Without Shell:

- Duplicate the source_ext
- Rename the source_ext_copy to your target_ext_name

Important to know is:

If your Extension-Directory has a _ inside like `vendor_extkey' the Namespace looks like this: VendorExtkey without the Underscore, but with the CamelCase Spelling.

#### Migrate Rootfiles

ext_emconf.php: Make your Changes.. this is not so important...

ext_localconf.php:

- In configurePlugin:

  - Change `OldVendor.ExtKey` to `NewVendor.ExtKey`
  - and the PluginName. More to configurePlugin [here](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_utility.html#a2f443aa1c5b36cce6aa57ee4e46fce23).
- In addPageTSConfig: Chage the following:

  - Name under elements
  - EXT: Paths
  - list_type

to your Vendor/ExtKey.

- In ext_typoscript_setup.txt: you have to change something like this, if this exists:

---

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
    subclasses {
        Tx_VendorExtkey_User = Vendor\VendorExtkey\Domain\Model\User
    }
}
Vendor\VendorExtkeyn\Domain\Model\User {
    mapping {
        tableName = fe_users
        recordType = Tx_VendorExtkey_User
    }
}
```

#### Migrate Classes: Model, Repository and ViewHelpers

If you have a Model in /Classes/Domain/Model/Yourmodel.php the first lines has to look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ExtKey\Domain\Model;
// Directory ext_key
```

OR

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extkey\Domain\Model;
// Directory extkey
```

In a Repository it looks the same: Simply change `Model` to `Repository`.

In a ViewHelper it a little different: Simply change `Domain\Model` to `ViewHelpers`

Everywhere in the Model you have to check something like this:

```
/**
 * @param \Vendor\ExtKey\Domain\Model\Yourmodel $yourmodel
 * @return void
 */
public function addLink(\Vendor\ExtKey\Domain\Model\Yourmodel $yourmodel)
{
    ...
}
```

Here you have to use the FQCN (Fully Quallified Class Name). Leave the other settings as they are.

#### Migrate Configuration

In each `TCA/Overrides/file.php` search for the Path: `LLL:EXT:source_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf` and change this to:

```
LLL:EXT:target_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf
```

Usually you can search for EXT:source_ext and replace this with EXT:target_ext.

#### Migrate: Configuration/TCA/sys_template.php

Usually here you find something like this:

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile('source_ext', 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Extension Name');

Change the source_ext to your target_ext. See more about addStaticFile [here](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_management_utility.html#a13ee6921557e1123c328a7dd3df9c576).

#### Migrate: Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
// Register Plugin
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'Vendor.ExtKey',
    'Plugin Name',
    'Plugin Title'
);
```

More about registerPlugin [here](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_utility.html#a815dc76c1a5695b5e8949c5b71eaca8a). If the parts in sys_template and tt_content aren't there look in the ext_tables.php -> move it to the right file as above, because ext_tables.php is marked as deprecated.

#### Migrate Configuration/TypoScript

Here just change EXT:source_ext to EXT:target_ext.

And if you have something like this inside:

```
## Override storagePid for UserGroups
Vendor\SourceExt\Domain\Model\UserGroup {
    newRecordStoragePid = {$plugin.tx_sourceext.settings.groupStoragePid}
```

just change the Vendor and the SourceExt to CamelCase spelling.

#### Migrate Templates, Layouts and Partials

Here you only have to migrate the Namespace, if you use a ViewHelper inside. Should appear in the first lines.

Change `{namespace shortcode=Vendor\SourceExt\ViewHelpers}` to `{namespace shortcode=NewVendor\TargetExt\ViewHelpers}`

---

I hope I could help. If I forgot something leave a comment.